# Expensive operations on floats in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point

I have a function in Haskell that operates on 2 (large) lists of floats and returns a list of floats.  I started with a simple summation, and am now looking for a more complicated operation that will take longer.  That's right - I really want to get slower!

I tried the following:

```
listOp :: (Floating a) => [a]->[a]->[a]
listOp _ [] = []
listOp [] _ = []
listOp (x:xs) (y:ys) = (sqrt ((x/y) / (y/x))) : (listOp xs ys)
```

Because of my (Win32) memory constraints, the lists are restricted to a length of 4 million when using Double.  The contents are randomly generated and evaluation is forced on the lists.

I takes about 5 seconds to generate each of the input lists.  I've tried various operations looking for an expensive operation `x+y`, `x*y`, `(x**y)**(y**x)` but the result list is always calculated sub 1 second (unless my timing code is bad).

Any suggestions for an expensive operation I could use on `x`and `y`?  Are the trig functions (sin, cos, etc) good candidates?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use laziness to let the lists stream? Than you can get arbitrary long lists in constant memory.

Comment: What are you doing to the resulting list?  Unless you make sure to force every element of the list nothing will happen.  And, btw, use `zipWith` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @FUZxxl I have reasons for not wanting lazy lists - I didn't want to muddy the waters with tangential discussions so I left them out.

Comment: @augustss I am forcing every element of the list. Thanks for the `zipWith` hint - that can come at the end.

Comment: Can you tell us more of the problem context?  Given the information provided, I can't think of any possible point.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate some function like sin N times where you can tune N until it's slow enough.  That will keep the FPU busy, which you seem to want for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

A nicely tunable expensive function is the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).  The runtime of the Ackermann function increases *very* rapidly -- it increases more quickly than exponential.

Comment: "More quickly than exponential" is a bit of an understatement here. I'm pretty sure the Ackermann function is overkill for what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
\x y -> unsafePerformIO (threadDelay 1000000 >> return x + y)
```

For CPU-y goodness, busy-loop.

```
loop 0 = ()
loop x = loop (x-1)
\x y -> loop 1000000000 `seq` x + y
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a genuinely expensive operation that will keep the CPU busy doing some work.  I should have made that clear, sorry.

Comment: Updated answer to peg your CPU.

Comment: On higher optimization levels (i.e. those that are worth benchmarking), that's probably optimized to `seq () (x + y)` and then to `x + y`.